# SQLAlchemy - How to add indirect relationships through more than one model?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to create indirect relationships between models in SQLAlchemy. I have models that are related together using join tables. The constraints of this project mean I cannot use foreign keys directly in the models, so I must use a separate join table. The relationships are configured using the `secondary` argument to `relationship`.

For example, I have code that looks like:

```py
class Deployment(Base):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    pod = relationship("Pod", secondary=FromDeploymentToPod, uselist=False)

class Pod(Base):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    containers = relationship("Container", secondary=FromPodToContainer)
    
class Container(Base):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)    

class FromDeploymentToPod(Base):
    from_id = Column(BigInteger, "deployment.id")
    to_id = Column(BigInteger, "pod.id")
    
class FromPodToContainer(Base):
    from_id = Column(BigInteger, "pod.id")
    to_id = Column(BigInteger, "container.id")
```

In this code I am able to access the `pod` relation on `Deployment` by doing `deployment.pod`, but I would also like to be able to access all `Container` models related to deployment by doing `deployment.containers`. This leaves me with 2 questions:

1. How could I create these indirect relations?
2. How can I generalize this pattern to work for any relation of any distance to the model?

I read the SQLAlchemy docs, and while these secondary relations are well documented I could not find any information on creating relations that are configured with more than 1 secondary table.